# How to enable printf() function from printing Boolean types in C with defining new identifier in printf("%ex",test())?

Tags: c, boolean, printf

I am trying to add new identifiers to printf() function to enable printing "true" and "false" .. Eg:printf("%boolean",test()); is this possible in c ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int boolean;
#define true 1
#define false 0

boolean test(int x){
return x%2==0?1:0;
                }

int main(){
printf("%s",test(5));
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: For home-grown conversion specifiers especially see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22114373/694576

Comment: i want to edit (over-ride) printf() function with adding new identifiers to its basic identifiers ("%s", "%d","%test") !
i do not want to use ternary operator , i already know it .

Comment: Please see the link specified (as "*GNU C library provides an API for adding custom specifiers*") in the answer I linked above.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
printf("%s",test(5));
```

to

```
printf("%s",(test(5))?"true":"false");
```

which tells `%s` to print `"true"` if `test(5)` returns a non-zero integer and `"false"` if `test(5)` returns 0.