# C printf : conditional format depending on the base of an int value

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I have an unsigned int variable x which value is comprised between from 0 and 0xFFFFF and I would like to print it in a way more readable for the user. 
If x is greater than 0xF000, print it in hexadecimal, else print it in decimal.
So something like this would do it

```
if (x > 0xF000) 
   printf("%#x", x);
else 
   printf("%u", x)
```

But I would like to know if there is an handier and smarter way to handle this, like conditional formatting for output depending of their value.

Comment: What you have is probably the easiest to read. I'd stop here unless given a very good reason to complicate things.

Comment: If your program's output is ever read by a machine, or by an uninitiated human, the changing representation could be very confusing.  If you really want to do this, I strongly recommend marking the output format somehow, perhaps by prefixing the hexadecimal numbers with `0x`, which you can do either with `"0x%x"` or `"%#x"`.

Comment: Besides the other problems mentioned, calling `printf` with a format which is not a single, constant string is arguably poor style.  It is disrecommended by some style guides.  I believe it is diagnosed by some compilers.  It means that the compiler can't, in general, do any checking for mismatches between the format string and the arguments.

Comment: See also [Why is printf with a single argument (without conversion specifiers) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290850) (though it's a somewhat different question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'conditional format' could be specified using the *ternary '?' operator*, as suggested in the comments:

```c
printf((x > 0xF000) ? "%#x" : "%u", x);
```

However, as also suggested in the comments, this doesn't really help in terms of readability.

You can also use a *string variable* as the format argument, for example (in this trivial case):

```c
char fmt[4];
if (x > 0xF000) strcpy(fmt, "%x");
else            strcpy(fmt, "%u"); // You haven't specified what type "x" is, so let's assume "unsigned".
printf(fmt, x);
```

Comment: The second approach is not good in case you wanted to add a new-line or something else.

Comment: @machine_1 - Well, assuming you make `fmt` a big enough buffer, you can put whatever you want (including newlines) into it. But I'm not saying it's the *best* way - just *one* way.

Comment: Wouldn't a buffer of size `3` be sufficient in the second example?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Of course, one could equally well use `char* fmt` and initialise to a string-literal.

Comment: Some compilers will issue a warning if the printf format string is not a string literal.

Comment: @bool - Just my habit - always prefer to allocate a 'bit too much' rather than 'not enough'.

Comment: @Ian Well they shouldn't! From [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/): `int printf ( const char * format, ... );` (implicit casting of non-const to const here is OK).

Comment: @Adrian See the comment I added in the question.  It's a debatable warning, but not indefensible.

Comment: @Steve I can understand (and even agree with) your comment/concern. However, it should be a warning from (maybe) a *code analyser* rather than a compiler. But, it depends also on whether one is using `C++` (IMHO, justified) or `C` (IMHO, unjustified) - question is tagged with both.

Comment: @Adrian Being pedantic, the variable `x` will have the wrong type for at least one of the format strings `%d` (expects an `int`) or `%x` (expects an `unsigned int`).

Comment: @Adrian Two points (though I'm not arguing with you; I like the freedom of using variable formats myself).  (1) Mismatch of `printf` arguments is bad.  Having the compiler check them is good.  But if the format is variable the compiler can't check.  Therefore variable formats are bad. (2) Some (including, I've heard, the maintainers of gcc) believe that having separate code analyzers is lame.  They're too much extra work to maintain, they're too likely to diverge from the compiler(s) in terms of the language accepted, and people might not run them.  Ergo, *all* the warnings go in the compiler.

Comment: See also [Why is printf with a single argument (without conversion specifiers) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290850) (though it's a somewhat different question).

Comment: Ok, I am sure now C does not provide native conditional formatting.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yeah! But my point about C++ vs C is that C is 'supposed to be' dangerous (it's human-readable assembler code - do what you want, *caveat emptor*, &c) whereas C++ is (or has become) strongly typed. But this is philosophy, and not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @Mahouk If you got something out of this, then we at SO have done our job! But maybe consider taking out the `C++` tag? (There are ways in *that* language to do conditional formatting, but not in C.)

Comment: @Adrian, Really? In this case, Can you tell more about it? it would be my pleasure to know it

Comment: @Mahouk You should post a separate question! And be **very specific** and **explicit** in your title. There are many folks here on SO far more 'clued-up' than I am on such methods.

Comment: @Adrian, Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975980/c-printing-with-conditional-format-depending-on-the-base-of-an-int-value