# C++: Printing with conditional format depending on the base of an int value

Tags: c++, format, cout

In c++, Is there any format specifier to print an unsigned in different base, depending on its value? A format specifier expressing something like this:

```
using namespace std; 
if(x > 0xF000) 
   cout << hex << "0x" << x;
else 
   cout << dec << x ;
```

Because I will have to do this a lot of times in my current project, I would like to know if c++ provides such a format specifier.

Comment: Seems to me that you just wrote the code, more or less, to do exactly what you're asking. Your question is unclear.

Comment: The `std::hex` is "sticky". You probably have to insert a `std::dec` somewhere e.g. `(x > 0xF000) ? cout << hex << "0x" << x << dec : cout << x ;` or `(x > 0xF000) ? cout << hex << "0x" << x : cout << dec << x ;`

Comment: **Don't use ternaries like that.** Very bad practice. Even though the `cout << x` is an expression that _can_ be a statement, and thus used in a ternary, don't. It's incredibly unreadable. **Use an `if` statement.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such functionality built-in to C++. You can use a simple wrapper to accomplish this, though:

```
struct large_hex {
    unsigned int x;
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const large_hex& lh) {
    if (lh.x > 0xF000) {
        return os << "0x" << hex << lh.x << dec;
    } else {
        return os << lh.x;
    }
}
```

Use as `cout << large_hex{x}`.

If you want to make the threshold configurable you could make it a second field of `large_hex` or a template parameter (exercise for the reader).

Comment: I use something along the line of `cout << large_hex{x}` quite often for io-manipulation, though I was never sure if it is idomatic or rather horrible. First time I see it somewhere else.

Comment: Most likely optimized by the compiler and amounts to semantic type stubbing. You're fine as long as it's clear from you're code what's happening. That's the biggest priority.