# How to make 0 values in array print nothing?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to append two arrays together into one big array, and then print the values of each one in columns. As of right now I have them printing in columns correctly, but I was wondering if there was a way to print blank space instead of the value 0 for when an array does not have any value in that instance.

I tried doing a for loop that prints off the values x1[i],x2[i], and x3[i]. (x1 and x2 are the two small arrays, x3 is the conjoined one). I have the for loop running for i is less than n1+n2 (the total number of items from the two separate arrays).

Here is my code:

```
append(n1,n2,&x1,&x2,&x3);
    
    printf("x1      x2      result\n");
    for(i;i<(n1+n2);i++){
    printf("\n%.1f      %.1f      %.1f",x1[i],x2[i],x3[i]);
```

Comment: How are you able to access `n1+1`th element of x1 in this print statement? It should be throwing garbage values. Right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C printf : conditional format depending on the base of an int value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958859/c-printf-conditional-format-depending-on-the-base-of-an-int-value)

Comment: If `x1` is an array, you shouldn't use `&x1` when passing it as an argument. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: Here is my result: 

x1      x2      result

1.1      0.7      1.1
2.3      1.6      2.3
4.2      3.2      4.2
0.0      1.3      0.7
0.0      0.0      1.6
0.0      0.0      3.2
0.0      0.0      1.3

Could I just use if-statements for when one of the arrays is 0.0 to print a blank space?

Comment: 0 is not the same as "does not have any value".

Comment: Are you talking about the elements that are outside the bounds of the array, e.g. `x1[i]` when `i >= n1` and `x2[i]` when `i >= n2`?

Comment: Yes, I just want them to show a blank space in my output as opposed to 0.0. For example, the first array only has three values. Every iteration after i = 3 I'd like for it to print blank space instead of 0.0.

Comment: @Annsh, `printf("%.1f", 0.000000001)` prints 0.0.  It that OK? Or should that get dropped too?

Comment: @Annsh Rather than "... to print blank space instead of the value 0 for when an array does not have any value in that instance." better as "... to print blank spaces instead of the value 0.0 for when an array element does not have the value of 0.0."

Answer (score 0):

Use separate `printf()` for each column. Then you can use an `if` statement to check if it's in range, and either print the array element or print spaces.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n1+n2); i++) {
    if (i < n1) {
        printf("%8.1f", x1[i]);
    } else {
        prinf("        ");
    }
    if (i < n2) {
        printf("%8.1f", x2[i]);
    } else {
        prinf("        ");
    }
    print("%8.1f\n", x3[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verbose answer making separate print statements depending on bounds check. You can also make it compact based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958859/c-printf-conditional-format-depending-on-the-base-of-an-int-value).

```
printf("x1      x2      result\n");
for (i = 0; i < (n1+n2); i++) {
  if (i < n1)                 // check x1 bounds
    printf("%.1f", x1[i]);
  else
    printf("    ");  

  printf("      ");

  if (i < n2)                 // check x2 bounds
    printf("%.1f", x2[i]);
  else
    printf("    "); 

  printf("      %.1f\n", x3[i]);      // x3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you asked.  Output is dependent on column and whether array index is non-zero or zero.  Please note that I had to change the logic very slightly (the array and its use) so I could attain a runnable example for proof of concept.

Tested, runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/afcbaTo74)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 23
int main( )
{
    int i=0, fmt;
    double x1[SIZE]={1,2,3,4,5,3,0,6,7,0,3,4,0,3,2,3,4,0,0,5,6,0,9};
    double *x2 = &x1[1];
    double *x3 = &x1[2];

    printf("x1       x2       result\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<SIZE-2; i++)
    {
        for(fmt=0; fmt<3; fmt++)
        {
            switch(fmt)
            {
                case 0:
                    if(x1[i])
                        printf("\n%.1f      ",x1[i]);   
                    else
                        printf("\n         ");   /* Just print space) */
                break;

                case 1:
                    if(x2[i])
                        printf("%.1f      ",x2[i]); 
                    else
                        printf("         ");     /* Just print space) */
                break;
                
                case 2:
                    if(x3[i])
                        printf("%.1f      ",x3[i]); 
                    else
                        printf("         ");     /* Just print space) */
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
    x1       x2       result

    1.0      2.0      3.0
    2.0      3.0      4.0
    3.0      4.0      5.0
    4.0      5.0      3.0
    5.0      3.0
    3.0               6.0
             6.0      7.0
    6.0      7.0
    7.0               3.0
             3.0      4.0
    3.0      4.0
    4.0               3.0
             3.0      2.0
    3.0      2.0      3.0
    2.0      3.0      4.0
    3.0      4.0
    4.0
                      5.0
             5.0      6.0
    5.0      6.0
    6.0               9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Code maintenance should be a consideration. You want to have few maintenance points in your code. The following (untested) may do what you want:

```
puts( "   x1   |   x2   | result |" );
for( int i = 0; i < n1 || i < n2; i++ ) { // NB: See below
    char *dFmt = "%8.1f|", *bFmt = "        |";

    printf( (i < n1) ? dFmt, bFmt, x1[i] );
    printf( (i < n2) ? dFmt, bFmt, x2[i] );
    print( dFmt, x3[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The changed conditional bails out of the loop after exhausting the largest of the two arrays. It's odd to imagine what "appending two arrays into a third" means. I'm betting the third array is calculated to be the sum of the other two (where care is taken to avoid accessing out of bounds.

Comment: I think the third array is the concatenation of the two first (e.g. [1,2,3] and [4,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5]), so the loop should run up to `n1+n2`.

Comment: @nielsen The problem statement is odd, and since there's no concrete demonstration of the OP's expected output, any interpretation seems plausible... What's the meaning of printing 3 arrays in parallel when the first values of `arr3[]` will be exactly the same as one of the others? Strange!! `:-)`