# Iterating through char* and comparing each char to another char

Tags: c, string, character, string-comparison, strcmp

I'm not well versed in c and I'm having issues with

1. iterating through a char* character by character
2. correctly comparing the individual character with another character

given a string like "abcda", I want to count the number of "a"s and return the count

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char** argv){
        char* string_arg;
        int counter = 0;
        if(argc == 2){
            for(string_arg = argv[1]; *string_arg != '\0'; string_arg++){
                printf(string_arg);
                printf("\n");
                /*given abcda, this prints
                abcda                    a
                bcda                     b
                cda        but i want    c
                da                       d 
                a                        a */

                if(strcmp(string_arg, "a") == 0){ //syntax + logical error
                    counter++;
                }
            }
         printf(counter);
         }
         else{
             printf("error");
         }
         return(0);
    }
```

I'm also not supposed to use strlen()

How do I compare one character at a time, correctly?

Comment: Side note: `printf(string_arg);` is dangerous. `string_arg` is user input, so it can be arbitrary string, including ones that contain `%`. It should be `printf("%s", string_arg);` or `fputs(string_arg, stdout);`.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh, I see. I'll be sure to implement that when I print the user input. In this case, they were there just so I could get a visual. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I seem to have left out the c when I wrote it up. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strcmp(string_arg, "a") == 0) { 
     counter++;
}
```

The call to `strcmp` is not appropriate in your case, as it compares **strings**. With this statement you compare a string starting at the element pointed to by `string_arg` with the string `"a"`, not the character constant `'a'`. Note that `"a"` is equal to `'a'`+ `'\0'`.

Instead, You need to compare `*string_arg` with `'a'`:

```
if (*string_array == 'a') { 
     counter++;
}
```

`puts(string_arg);` prints a string. That is not what you want. You want to print only a single character. Use `printf("%c", *string_arg);` instead to print a character.

Note that something like `printf(string_arg);` is dangerous. Always use a format specifier: `printf("%c", *string_arg);`. Reasony why is explained under the following link:

[Why is printf with a single argument (without conversion specifiers) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290850/why-is-printf-with-a-single-argument-without-conversion-specifiers-deprecated)

---

This shall be what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    char* string_arg;
    int counter = 0;

    if (argc == 2){

        for (string_arg = argv[1]; *string_arg != '\0'; string_arg++) {

            printf("%c", *string_arg);
            printf("\n");

            if (*string_arg == 'a') { 
                counter++;
            }
        }

        printf("%d times character 'a' encountered.", counter);
     }
     else {
        printf("Error: No second argument at the program invocation!");
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this, worked. My vote doesn't show because I have <15 reputation though. As for the printing of the remaining parts, I didn't want that. It was just supposed to be a visualization of the fact that I wanted each loop to only focus on a single character.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I recently noticed what your intention was. I corrected my code already.

Answer (score 1):

- `arg` isn't declared. It seems it should be `argc`.
- `printf(string_arg);` is dangerous because `string_arg` is an user input, which can contain arbitrary string, which may include `%`.
- `strcmp()` if for comparing strings. You can use simply `==` to compare characters.
- `printf(counter);` is also wrong.
- `}` at the end of `main` function is missing.

example fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char* string_arg;
    int counter = 0;
    if(argc == 2){
        for(string_arg = argv[1]; *string_arg != '\0'; string_arg++){
            puts(string_arg);
            /*given abcda, this prints
            abcda                    a
            bcda                     b
            cda        but i want    c
            da                       d 
            a                        a */

            if(*string_arg == 'a'){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", counter);
    }
    else{
        printf("error");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `arg` was just a typo by writing the question. Already fixed by OP.

Comment: this does address the syntax errors but it doesn't address the logical error of the loop. The comparison should be between "a" and "a" not "abcda" and "a". Even that is not happening on the last iteration of the loop @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio