# How does printf("%d",x) work/interpreted?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I am wondering how exactly `printf("%d",x)` is interpreted.  All I know that the compiler reserve a memory to put `'%'`,`'%d'`,`'\0'` and returns its address to `printf`, and then it prints the second argument `x` based on the format specifier that we indicated.

So if I use for example `int x=5;  char *p="%d";  printf(p,x)`, is it the same thing as `printf("%d",x)`?

Comment: It's actually `const char p[] = "%d";` but for the rest, yes.

Comment: Please explain what is puzzling you or which detail you want explained. Currently the question is unclear to me by and I have the impression that the answer is "Yes" (with dxiv details), but you could have found that by trying. So what is your question?

Comment: Do you wonder how [variadic fucntions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104628/technically-how-do-variadic-functions-work-how-does-printf-work) in general?

Comment: @Yunnosch i did try it and it worked but i don't understand how it worked

Comment: @churill yes please

Comment: What about it don't you understand?   In both cases, the format string is `%d`.  The fact that in one instance the argument is passed as a string literal and in the other instance the address is passed in a variable is a trivial detail.  It is no different than the difference betweeen `foo(5);` and `int x = 5; foo(x);` (assuming an appropriate declaration).

Comment: @dxiv ... in C, a string literal has type `/*readonly*/ char [N]`; it is not `const` qualified. It may be one of the differences between C and C++ I'm not aware of.

Comment: @pmg Right, a string literal has `const` array type in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) though not in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is `printf("%d",x)` is interpreted?

OP's explanation is one potential partial description of code.

Yet C and C++ are typically compiled, not interpreted. Compilers today can  examine `printf("%d",x)` and  emit code like `print_an_integer(x);`.

---

With OP's example, the 2 codes are *functionally* the same, yet a compiler may not recognize optimization potential as described above with the first code.

```
int x=5;
// In C++, should be `const char *p="%d";`
char *p="%d";
printf(p,x);
// same as ????
printf("%d",x);
```

Instead the format *string* passed to `printf()` is processed, looking for characters to print and print specifiers. The print specifiers, in turn, get the next argument and process them accordingly.

If the format string and the arguments do not match, like `printf("%f",x)` or `p="%d";  printf(p, 5.0)`, the result is *undefined behavior*.

---

> ... how exactly ...

A compiler is allowed wide latitude on forming the emitted code. It needs to meet the equivalent functional requirements of a virtual machine - not OP's explanation.  Any exact explanation is compiler and code dependent.

Answer (score 3):

One mildly curious aspect of C is that the `printf` function, although it's an unusual function, is still very much a function, so all the usual rules apply.  And for *any* function `f()`, if you have a call with a complicated argument, like

```
f(complicatedargument1, arg2, arg3);
```

you can *always* change it to

```
sometype tmp = complicatedargument1;
f(tmp, arg2, arg3);
```

If you haven't learned it yet, you should definitely learn it at some point: expressions in C (and most programming languages) are very, very general.  So you can not only have

```
a + b
```

you can have

```
(arbitrarily-complicated expression with many subexpressions) + (arbitrarily-complicated expression with many subexpressions)
```

You can not only have

```
f(a, b, c)
```

you can also have

```
f((complicated subexpression), (another complicated subexpression), (yet another complicated subexpression))
```

(And if you want to get really crazy, it turns out that you can replace `f` by a complicated subexpression, too.)

And because expressions are general like this, the answer to your second question just *has* to be "yes".

So in principle there is nothing wrong with writing

```
char *p = "%d";
int x = 5;
printf(p, x);
```

and this will indeed behave exactly as if you had written

```
printf("%d", x);
```

To be very clear: this works because `printf`'s first argument is a string.  The vast majority of the time it's a constant string, but there's no reason it can't be some other expression of type "string", such as the variable `p`.  (Footnote: C doesn't really have a "string" type, but that's a separate topic which I'd rather not get into just now.)

In practice, though, there are one or two differences, related to the fact that `printf` is peculiar.

One issue is that since there are so many easy mistakes you can make when calling `printf`, good compilers try to help you out, by checking for some of these mistakes.  If you accidentally write

```
int x = 5;
printf("%f", x);
```

that's not going to work, and gcc helpfully says "warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'".  This is something very special that the compiler does, but it's typically able to do it *only* if the first argument to `printf` is a string literal.  If you were to write

```
int x = 5;
char *p = "%f"
printf(p, x);
```

the compiler probably wouldn't be able to perform this check for you.

The other issue is that printf can be dangerous.  Very occasionally, you might be doing something exotic where you wanted to use different format strings under different circumstances, like this:

```
int x = 123;
char *p;
if(somecondition)
     p = "%x\n";
else p = "%d\n";
printf(p, x);
```

This either prints `x` in decimal or hexadecimal, depending on `somecondition`.  That's perfectly fine, but what if you got *really* crazy and wrote:

```
int x = 123;
char fmt[20];
printf("What format would you like to use? ");
fgets(fmt, 20, stdin);
printf(fmt, x);
```

Now the user can actually *type in* the format string that `printf` is going to use!  And this will work, too, and you might want to type it in now and play with it.

...And if you're feeling adventurous, and you do type it in, and after playing with it with formats like `%d` and `%x` and `%010o`, see what happens if you type in the format string `%n`.  On my computer, at least, this *crashes*!  What's up with that?

Well, `%n` is a very special format specifier for `printf`, that lets you find out how many characters it's printed so far.  But the corresponding argument for `%n` has to be a *pointer* to an int.  So in this case it will do something like wrongly interpreting the value of `x` as a pointer, meaning that it tries to write to location 123 or something, which is illegal, and results in a crash.

So, the bottom line here is that using something other than a constant string literal as the first argument to `printf` is risky, because the compiler won't be able to check for mistakes.  And if the format string ends up being derived from something uncontrolled, like user input, this can be downright dangerous.

So as a general rule, it's a good idea not to make much use of this freedom.  That is, it's a good idea to keep most or all of your printf format strings as constant string literals.  Be careful if you ever use an arbitrary expression there instead, because the compiler can't check it.  And unless you're absolutely sure you can trust your users, don't ever let them specify the printf format your program will use, because that will let them crash or possibly even subvert your program.

For this reason, some style guides mandate that the first argument to `printf` be a string literal.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290850/why-is-printf-with-a-single-argument-without-conversion-specifiers-deprecated/).

Comment: Sounds to me like somebody could turn your `printf()` into a `goto` if they use the right format string and arguments

Comment: @puppydrum64 Yup!  That's exactly what "possibly even subvert your program" means.