# Is 'printf("%s", user_input)' dangerous?

Tags: c, security, user-input

I know that `printf(user_input)` is dangerous, but what about `printf("%s", user_input)`? Is this generally safe as long `user_input` is NUL terminated?

Comment: If `user_input` is guaranteed to be a null terminated string, it is fine - although I prefer `fputs(user_input, stdout);` if no formatting is needed.

Comment: More importantly, do you understand *why* `printf(user_input)` is unsafe?

Comment: Yes, because the user would then be able to fully take control of the format specifiers.

Comment: As indicated by the "If `user_input` is guaranteed to be a null terminated string" in the first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77082134/is-printfs-user-input-dangerous#comment135887272_77082134), the question cannot be answered without seeing the code that defines and/or allocates `user_input` and how the user input is read.

Comment: In my case, it is guaranteed to be NUL terminated. I will add this to the question.

Comment: Surely there are other assumptions. The null-terminator must be within the allocated size of `user_input` for one

Comment: All strings in C are null-terminated by definition. A non-null-terminated array of characters is just an array of characters, not a string. Passing something that is not a string to `printf("%s", ...)` is just as dangerous as passing something that is not a string to `strcat` or `fputs` or `strlen`. Can you do `strlen(user_input)`?

Comment: That is correct! No, you can't as long you've not made sure it was capped and terminated before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that `printf(user_input)` is dangerous, but what about `printf("%s", user_input)`? Is this generally safe?

The latter is among the replacements commonly recommended for the former.  It resolves [the issue that makes `printf(user_input)` *particularly* dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290989/2402272).

There remain more general issues such as what happens if `user_input` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string, or if the string contains characters that elicit special behavior from the output device, or if the standard output stream has been closed, or maybe other things.

I'm not sure "generally safe" is a good description of all that, but perhaps it is indeed what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that printf(user_input) is dangerous, but what about printf("%s", user_input)? Is this generally safe as long user_input is NUL terminated?

It is not dangerous *per se* but it can be subject to some exploit when other cases converge.  You can use specific input (like e.g. `"%p,%p,%p,%p,%p,%p,%p,%p\n"`) to provoke a stack dump of the stack upto the call to the `printf()` function at that point and reveal part of your program structure (a complete, formatted stack trace of your program can be obtained this way). It's (by far) better to check what the `user_input` holds before doing a `printf()` blindly of a user provided format string, or just do

```
    printf("%s", user_input);
```

or

```
    fputs(user_input, stdout);
```

**Note:** Of course, it has already been suggested about crashing your program by using the `"%s"` format specifier that dereferences a pointer to enfoce a `SIGSEGV`, but crashing a program is many times non dangerous for security.   The option I have suggested can reveal the attacker the architecture you are using, probably the compiler used and parameters used (and local variable contents) from all the stack frames in your program.  Based on this, it is probable that further attacks (or better DOS) can be issued.