# Reading boolean with fscanf

Tags: c, boolean, scanf

Today I encountered a problem with scanf functions.  Assume that you have a structure like the following example.

```
struct structA{
  bool bVal;
  int nVal;
}
```

If you run the following code

```
structA a;

a.nVal = 7;
...// Assume that we read a text file and the only text is "0"
fscanf(fp,"%d",&a.bVal);

printf("\n a.bVal=%d",a.bVal);
printf("\n a.nVal=%d",a.nVal);
```

It will print

```
 a.bVal = 0
 a.nVal = 0
```

The reason is that the fscanf function assumes a.bVal is an integer and overwrites the a.nVal first 3 bytes. This problem can be solved by the following dirty solution.

```
structA a;

a.nVal = 7;
...// Assume that we read a text file and the only text is "0"
int nBVAL;
fscanf(fp,"%d",&nBVAL);
a.bVal = nBVAL;

printf("\n a.bVal=%d",a.bVal);
printf("\n a.nVal=%d",a.nVal);
```

My question is that is there a cleaner and straightforward way of avoiding this problem beside the solution explained?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the printf format specifier for bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool)

Comment: @EugeneSh. that post says bool is promoted when *reading*. OP's problem is with *writing*

Answer (score 8):

The solution you're proposing is the only portable one.

There is no conversion specifier for `_Bool`. There's also no guarantee about the storage size of a `_Bool`, except that it has at least `CHAR_BIT` bits. Even if you **knew** the size and tried something like `%hhd`, entering anything other than `1` or `0` would create a value that's invalid for a `_Bool` (`scanf()` would access the object through a `char` pointer, possibly writing the *padding bits* of the `_Bool`).

The only safe thing to do is to take input of a type you can handle and convert this to a `_Bool` where needed, as you're doing in your example.

Note there's no similar problem with `printf()`. A `_Bool` passed to `printf()` is promoted to `int`, so `%d` is fine.