# How to call a bool function in main?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to create a function by which I can check if the data entered match a triangle or not. I managed to do the function, but I am having a trouble in calling it in main. I want the output to be either true or false.
Thanks.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool triangle(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{
// This is where I miss the point and need help with. A little explanation would be great. Thanks.
    printf("%d", triangle(3, -7, 8));
}

bool triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (c + b <= a))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}
```

Comment: What is not working ? What do you get as an output ? What do you mean by "I miss the point" ?

Comment: "I am having a trouble" is not a problem description. What happens when you compile/run that code? Why is that wrong? What should happen instead?

Comment: Did you perhaps want this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool

Comment: @underscore_d Well, tbh, OP actually states the desired behavior and even though it would be good to explicitly state the actual behavior, it's pretty obvious in this case.

Comment: If i'm not wrong about the data types, it should be `_Bool`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Lucas That's the keyword. stdbool.h defines the macro bool, and I think cs50.h includes that header.

Comment: Oh, thanks for introducing me to `stdbool.h`. @klutt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition operator to evaluate the return of this function.
if triangle returns true (1) - "true" will be printed.
Otherwise, "false" will be printed.

```
printf("%s", triangle(3, -7, 8) ? "true" : "false");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use printf when ever your condition is validated to print true or false

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool triangle(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{
// This is where I miss the point and need help with. A little explanation would be great. Thanks.
    if(triangle(3, -7, 8))
    printf("True");
    else printf("False");
}

bool triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (c + b <= a))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}
```

Comment: This won't work you need to add an additional header to use bool

Comment: It depend's on the compiler in my case i used c++ compiler which already know the bool but in case of gcc you are right. I'll update it.

Comment: `bool` is defined in `cs50.h`

Comment: @Jona there is more than a solution to use bool in C. Both solutions are are valid.

Comment: @BouraouiAl-MoezL.A I agree. My remark was more targeted to Sai Sreenivas .

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use bool it's a good practice to add an extra include (since bool is not primitive type in C):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

(Or) you can use _Bool type, which doesn't need any additional headers.

You can do something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

_Bool triangle(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s", triangle(3, -7, 8) ? "true" : "false");
}

_Bool triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (c + b <= a))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;


}
```

Comment: Now the answer doesn't explain why it uses `_Bool` instead, but it doesn't need to do that.

Comment: @underscore_d added!

Comment: `C99` added `_Bool` as a new built-in data type. If you don't know. @underscore_d

Comment: `bool` is defined in `cs50.h`

Comment: @Lucas I know that, but the pre-edit post just dropped the `#include <cs50.h>` and changed `bool` to `_Bool` without explanation; that was my point.

Comment: @Jona you know, I'm sure that this will be defined in `cs50.h` but that is not a standard header file. Actually I didn't know about that until I searched for `CS50`, which is just an online course on `edX`, so it's better to mention about anything new which you are including in your code.

Comment: Have you checked, what's inside that `cs50.h` header file? Perhaps, they might be using `#include <stdbool.h>` inside that file. @Jona

Comment: @Lucas As `bool` was neither the issue reported by the OP, neither an underlying issue. I don't understand why it's the first thing mentioned in the answer. I would find it more relevant as a later remark. My point was NOT to focus on this `bool`.

Comment: @Jona Sorry for the miscommunication. Actually ```cs50.h``` is not a standard header. So I just wanted to add that point but I didn't mention it in the correct way. Now I've edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int main(void)
{
// This is where I miss the point and need help with. A little explanation would be great. Thanks.
   bool iden = triangle(3, -7, 8);
   if ( iden == true ) printf( "true" );
   else printf("false");
}
```

If you use

```
int main(void)
{
// This is where I miss the point and need help with. A little explanation would be great. Thanks.
    printf("%d", triangle(3, -7, 8));
}
```

You will get `0`, because of it return `false`.

So,if it return `true`, you will get `1`