# CS50 valid triangle — incorrect code output

Tags: c, cs50

The code below compiles, runs, and takes input, but it does not output true or false as intended. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

//int add_two_ints(int a, int b);
bool valid_triangle (float a, float b, float c);
int main (void)
{

        float a = get_float("Enter Side 1:");
        float b = get_float("Enter Side 2:");
        float c = get_float("Enter Side 3:");
}

bool valid_triangle (float a, float b, float c)
{   //checks if two sides are greater than one
    if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (b + c <= a))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //checks for positive sides
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }
     //if conditions are met print true
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't call `valid_triangle`.

Comment: Sorry can you explain please, still quite new to c/programming.

Comment: You have defined a function but you never call it. In `main` add `bool r = valid_triangle(a, b, c);`

Comment: Once you call `valid_triangle()`, you need to fix the logic in the function — the test for overlong sides is incorrect (`<=` vs `>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from what i see in your code that you **didn't call the function** " **valid_triangle** " to consulte the output of it ..

Comment: Thank you, I have called the function in main as below; `valid_triangle (a,b,c);  
bool result = valid_triangle(a,b,c);  
printf("%d\n",result)` 
however, I am getting the outputs 1 and 0

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code will run unless it is called in the `main` function. `main` is what runs when you start your code.

Your `valid_triangle` function has only been *defined*, telling the rest of the code how it works and what kinds of values it accepts, but it will not run unless called. Add a call to your `valid_triangle` function within `main`, and it will execute the function based on its definition.

```
int main (void)
{

        float a = get_float("Enter Side 1:");
        float b = get_float("Enter Side 2:");
        float c = get_float("Enter Side 3:");
        bool isValid = valid_triangle(a, b, c);
}
```

By adding this final line into main, the program will run your function with the three triangle sides and collect the output in a `boolean` value. How you use the value is up to you. Just make sure it is written in `main`, or is called by `main`.

---

EDIT: Your `printf` function is using the `%d` identifier, which means take the next argument (`result`) and treat it like an integer (0 for false, 1 for true). C does not have a similar identifier for boolean values because they are typically used to control portions of the code, and not be the direct output.

There are many ways to print out *true* or *false*, but here is a more beginner-friendly version:

```
// Check if result is true
if (result)
{
    printf("%s", "true");
}
else 
{
    printf("%s", "false");
}
```

Depending on the boolean value of `result`, the code will print a different string to correspond to that value. To see the most condensed form that accomplishes this, see [What is the printf format specifier for bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool).

Comment: Thank you, I have called the function in main as below; 

`valid_triangle (a,b,c);

bool result = valid_triangle(a,b,c);

printf("%d\n",result)`

however, I am getting the outputs 1 and 0

Comment: @Charlesu49 I have added an explanation to your follow-up. The second code-block should appear in `main` after calling `valid_triangle`.