# What's the role of format specifiers in C?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I wrote this code to "find if the given character is a digit or not":

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    printf("enter a character");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("%c", ch>='0'&&ch<='9');
    return 0;
}
```

This got compiled, but after taking the input it didn't give any output.  However, after changing `%c` in the second to last line to the `%d` format specifier, it indeed worked. I'm a bit confused as to why `%d` worked but `%c` didn't, event though the variable is of `char` datatype.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't understand, sorry, I'm basically just starting with C.

Comment: @Lundin Oops ... need more coffee. I'll defer posting an answer, as you can probably do better than I would.

Comment: @AdrianMole Well I guess I have to, now that I reopened it... :)

Comment: `ch>='0'&&ch<='9'` evaluates to `0` or `1` neither of which are printable characters.

Comment: I got it that, to print boolean i.e. 1 for true and 0 for false, we need to use %d format specifier right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Characters in C are really just numbers in a token table. The `%c` is mainly there to do the translation between the alphanumeric token table that humans like to read/write and the raw binary that the C program uses internally.

The expression `ch>='0'&&ch<='9'` evaluates to `1` or `0` which is a raw binary integer of type `int` (it would be type `bool` in C++). If you attempt to print that one with `%c`, you'll get the [symbol table character](https://www.asciitable.com/) with index 0 or 1, which isn't even a printable character (0-31 aren't printable). So you print a non-printable character... either you'll see nothing or you'll see some strange symbols.

Instead you need to use `%d` for printing an integer, then `printf` will do the correct conversion to the printable symbols `'1'` and `'0'`

---

As a side-note, make it a habit to always end your (sequence of) printf statements with `\n` since that "flushes the output buffer" = actually prints to the screen, on many systems. See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) for details

Comment: Yep, got it! Thanks for clearing the doubt and the tip!

Answer (score 1):

In a memory, int take 4 bytes of memory you are trying to storing the int values in a character which will return the ascii value not a int value in %c if you are using a %d which will return the int value which are storing in a memory of 4 bytes memory.

Comment: "int take 4 bytes of memory" is [*not* always true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438985).