# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error while passing string to bool function

Tags: c

I keep getting this error when I try to pass these char values to bool function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
    
bool checksub(char *s1, char *v) {
  if (*s1==*v){
    return true;
  }
}
    
int main(void) {
  printf(checksub("a","a"));
}
```

Is that why I keep getting this error or is it a different reason?

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: you cannot printf return value of checksub("a", "a") without format string

Comment: Light, save time.  Enable all compiler warnings to see trouble with `printf(checksub("a","a"));`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has two problems. First of all, the `checksub` function has no return value in case the condition is `false`. The second problem is that in `printf` you are missing the format of the value you would like to print.

This is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


bool checksub(const char *s1, const char *v) {
  return (*s1 == *v);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", checksub("a","a"));
}
```

I think that in `C` the best way to compare string is usign the `strcmp`standard function. So, the `checksub` becomes:

```
bool checksub(const char *s1, const char *v) {
  return !strcmp(s1, v);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return (*s1==*v)`?

Comment: @blackbrandt Of curse is possible! More clean ;) Thank you

Comment: Aside:  When using referenced data that is not changed, more applicable to use `const` as in `bool checksub(const char *s1, const char *v) ...`

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has to do with using printf with bools
I am not sure who you compiled the program because it gave me errors with:

```
tmp.c:11:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘printf’
```

which hints to the problem you should call printf with strings if you want to print bools use any of these methods here:
[What is the printf format specifier for bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool)
if you want more details about printf use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm