# How to do file I/O with bool in C?

Tags: c, c11

Should I treat a `bool` variable like an `int` when doing file I/O?
I mean is it correct to use the following code snippet?

```c
bool b = true;
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
...
fprintf(fp1, "%d", b);
fscanf(fp2, "%d", &b);
```

I'd like to know the answer based on ISO C specifications.

Comment: Which version of ISO C?

Comment: FWIW, `bool` will get promoted to `int` anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool

Comment: @Dai, I'm mainly interested in C11 here.

Comment: Added [tag:c11] tag based on the comment above.

Comment: @Dai There's no promotion in case of scanf. So it will just merrily crash & burn.

Comment: @Lundin _yikes_ - how'd the ISO C commitee justify that one?

Comment: @Dai Bool was added mostly as an afterthought and the C99 implementation of it was half-hearted. That begin said, stdio.h is a dangerous crap library and the root of the problem is that it was included in C89 in the first place, instead of enforcing a better lib suitable for professional use. Too much care was put into backwards-compatibility against old crap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I treat a bool variable like an int when doing file I/O?

No, not for input.
Yes, OK to use for output as the `bool` is converted to an `int` as part of being a `...` argument and that `int` matches `"%d"`.

> I mean is it correct to use ...

Not certainly.  It might work. It is *undefined behavior* (UB).

> I'd like to know the answer based on ISO C specifications.

There is no C specified way to read a `bool` via `fscanf()` and friends.

- `bool` lacks a `scanf()` input specifier.
- The size of `bool` may differ from `int`.  It might be the same as `char` or others.
- If input like `"0"`, `"1"` used and `"true"`, `"false"` not needed, read in an `int` and convert.

```
bool b = true;
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
...
fprintf(fp1, "%d", b);
int tmp;
fscanf(fp2, "%d", &tmp);
b = tmp;
```

- Alternatively, use a string.

```
char tmp[2];
fscanf(fp2, "%1[0-1]", tmp);
b = tmp[0] == '1';
```

- Additional work needed to accept `"t"`, `"FalsE"`, ...
- Of course the return value of `scanf()` should be checked.
- I'd consider a helper function:

```
Rough idea.  (Not really that great, just for illustration.)

// Read `bool` from `stdin`. Return 1 (success), EOF(end-of-file) and 0 in other cases.
int scan_bool(bool *b) {
  char buf[2];
  int cnt = scanf("%1[01tfTF]", buf);
  if (cnt != 1) {
    return cnt;
  }
  *b = buf[0] == '1' || buf[0] == 't' || buf[0] == 'T';
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, "the size of `bool` may differ from `int`. It might be the same as `char` or others" is why you think a boolean value can't be read with `fscanf()`. In my case, it is guaranteed that `true` is saved as 1 and `false` as 0. So I think even if `bool` is internally a `char`, it is big enough to store 1 and 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: @apadana "Am I missing something?" Yes. `true` is `1`. `int i = 1; char c = 1; float f = 1; void *v = 1; complex float cf = 1.0;` are all cases where the object has the value of 1, yet they can differ in the memory layout. With `fscanf(fp2, "%d", &b);`, `&b` is a `bool *`, not a `bool` and it is a pointer to `fscanf()` that expects a `int *`. `fscanf()` can use different ways to save data, depending on the the _type_ -& those are different types (of pointers). I think a `bool` value can't be read with `fscanf()` because the C library spec does not define a way, unlike `int, char, double, ...`

Comment: @apadana "even if bool is internally a char, it is big enough to store 1 and 0" --> Yes a `char` is big enough to store the value of `false` and `true`: zero and one.  So is every other basic type.  The simple thing is that C does not have is a _specified_ way to use `fscanf()` (and friends) to read a `bool`.

Comment: Let's suppose an `int` has 32 bits. Are you saying that when `fscanf()` sees `"%d"`, it  writes 32 bits in the memory location pointed by the `&b`, so *corrupting* 3 bytes of memory in case a `bool` occupies one single byte?

Comment: Otherwise, I see big difference between representation of a `float` and an integer in memory. A `char` is simply the 8 lowest significant bits of an `int`, while `float` is a totally different animal.

Comment: @apadana "so corrupting 3 bytes of memory in case a bool occupies one single byte?", yes, that is one problem.  Another is that the one byte written into the `bool` is not certainly the correct `bool` value.  Remember it is UB.  All sorts of troubles are possible including a bus fault from the incorrectly aligned address.

Answer (score 2):

OP is not asking for an alternate, yet the following, untested<sup>*1</sup> code, can gives ideas.  It tries to follow the spirit of `fscanf()` and accepts "0", "1", and caseless "t", "f", "true", "false".

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* 
 * Read a 'bool'.
 * 
 * Read stream until:
 * * ignore leading white-space.
 * * a complete case-less match to: "0", "1", "f", "t", "false", "true",
 * * end-of-file, or input error.
 * Non-matching characters are pushed back.
 *
 * On success, assign *b as true or false (1 or 0).
 *
 * Return 1 on success,
 * EOF on input error or immediate end-of-file.
 * 0 otherwise.
 */
int fscan_bool(FILE *inf, bool *b) {
  int first_ch;
  do {
    first_ch = fgetc(inf);
  } while (isspace(first_ch));
  if (first_ch == '0' || first_ch == '1') {
    *b = (first_ch == '1');
    return 1;
  }
  if (first_ch == EOF) {
    return EOF;
  }
  int buf[5];
  buf[0] = first_ch;
  first_ch = tolower(first_ch);
  if (first_ch != 'f' && first_ch != 't') {
    ungetc(buf[0], inf);
    return 0;
  }

  bool value = (first_ch == 't');
  static const char *ft[2] = {"false", "true"};
  const char *match = ft[value];
  for (unsigned i = 1; match[i]; i++) {
    buf[i] = fgetc(inf);
    int next_ch = tolower(buf[i]);
    if ((next_ch == EOF) && !feof(inf)) { // Input error
      return EOF;
    }
    if (next_ch != match[i]) {
      do {
        // Attempt to unget all "next" characters.
        // The first attempt should work if not EOF.
        // Subsequent ones may work, may fail.
        ungetc(buf[i--], inf);
      } while (i > 0);
      break;
    }
  }
  *b = value;
  return 1;
}
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>  Turns out thorough testing is tricky.

Code review request for similar code and test harness [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/287905/29485).

Comment: [For testing](https://github.com/nickeldan/scrutiny).  Pardon the self-promotion.